# How to PSD to iphone app

Tags: ios, psd

I recently designed an iphone app in photoshop and asked developer to code that. That developer sent me a horrible image to define what he is expecting me as deliverable.

[Here is the link to the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fyqb53jkmbclqx/example.png?dl=0)

Since I've lot of screens so it will take a lot of time to make examples of each screens like that. That developer doesn't know anything about PSD and says that he had developed previous 10 application in the same way. I google out about what is the professional way to achieve the task but didn't find any good solution.

I'm front end developer and what I do? I simply take PSDs and measure all stuff as described in above image my self.

Please write how should we proceed? What are the best practices to follow.

Comment: In my opinion, rather than measuring exact pixel sizes between controls and aiming for a pixel perfect design, use autolayout and the Apple standard layout margins. Follow the iOS HIG (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) and you won't go far wrong.

Comment: My recommendation is to look for a different developer. One good reason is what Robotic is trying to convey. There should be no one set sized app, because there isn't just one iOS device. You should be able to send mock-ups of just the views and what you want it to look like (not measurements) (i.e, Favorites view, Home, Friends, etc) and the developer will be able to navigate the internal details.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is resizing the png to the height of an real IPhone screen. That way you'll be able to open it in photoshop and use the measure tool.
So, what you'll have to do is: Crop the image to the screen (so the picture is the 'screen' of the iPhone), set height in pixels and measure!

Good luck